# PHP restart Orange Funbox 2.0 internet

Tags: php, curl

Exact model: **Sagemcom CS 50001**

I was trying to write a script in PHP/CURL to automatically reset internet in Orange FunBox, but it doesn't work... login seems to work fine, as well as session... because when login fails, I get error in response to restart command... "Access denied"... ok... but now there is no error, response the same as in browser, but restart doesn't take place... any idea why?

**Step one: Login.**

```
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

$curl = curl_init('http://192.168.1.1/authenticate?username=admin&password=admin');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'username=admin&password=admin');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, '/tmp/ipreset_cookie.jar');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, '/tmp/ipreset_cookie.txt');
```

**Step two: Send connection restart request.**

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8','X-Context:'.$context,'X-Prototype-Version:1.7','X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest','Referer:http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html'));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NeMo/Intf/data:setFirstParameter');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, '{"parameters":{"name":"Enable","value":1,"flag":"ppp","traverse":"down"}}');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_exec($curl);
```

What I am getting is an answer that `status:null`, no error (the same answer as in browser when it works)... but nothing happens.

The problem may be the way that CURL encodes the POST, but not sure about it... normally by browser it is send in payload.

Second idea is that when in browser, it sends some mass of requests to different interfaces, and cookies are much bigger than session id... someting like:

`46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl;46db1eb1/context=$context; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl;'`

The problem is that I can't add that in CURL without losing session cookie... when I add `Cookie` header with that, it adds second `Cookie` header in request... and I guess it's wrong.

The funny is that... when I copy to CURL command line a request to restart connection (from Browser), curl gives me `Gateway timeout` error... pretty weird, as same request worked before from browser...

**This is what Fiddler returns as CURL script export from whole procedure (since login to restart). Maybe it will help...**

```
curl -k -i --raw -o 0.dat "http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "If-None-Match: 46db1eb1"
curl -k -i --raw -o 1.dat "http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl" -H "If-None-Match: 46db1eb1"
curl -k -i --raw -o 2.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/UserInterface:getLanguage" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1"
curl -k -i --raw -o 3.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/Devices:get" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "X-Sah-Request-Type: idle" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1"
curl -k -i --raw -o 4.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/eventmanager:get_events" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: null" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-4-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "X-Sah-Request-Type: idle" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl"
curl -k -i --raw -o 5.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NMC/OrangeTV:getIPTVStatus" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "X-Sah-Request-Type: idle" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl"
curl -k -i --raw -o 6.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/VoiceService/VoiceApplication:listTrunks" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "X-Sah-Request-Type: idle" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl"
curl -k -i --raw -o 7.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NMC:getWANStatus" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "X-Sah-Request-Type: idle" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl"
curl -k -i --raw -o 8.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NMC/Wifi:get" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "X-Sah-Request-Type: idle" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl"
curl -k -i --raw -o 9.dat -X POST -d "username=admin&password=admin" "http://192.168.1.1/authenticate?username=admin&password=admin" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept: text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl"
curl -k -i --raw -o 10.dat "http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:25 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)" -H "If-None-Match: 46db1eb1"
curl -k -i --raw -o 11.dat "http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:25 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.); 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl" -H "If-None-Match: 46db1eb1"
curl -k -i --raw -o 12.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/UserManagement:getUsers" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:31 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 13.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NMC:getLANIP" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:31 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 14.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/Devices:get" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:31 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 15.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/DHCPv4/Server/Pool/default:getStaticLeases" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:31 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 16.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NMC:getWANStatus" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:31 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 17.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/Devices:get" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:31 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 18.dat "http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8" -H "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigNetworkDhcp.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:31 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)" -H "If-None-Match: 46db1eb1"
curl -k -i --raw -o 19.dat "http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "Accept: */*" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma, sdch" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:31 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.); 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl" -H "If-None-Match: 46db1eb1"
curl -k -i --raw -o 20.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/UserManagement:getUsers" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:33 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 21.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NMC:getWANStatus" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:34 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 22.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NeMo/Intf/data:getMIBs" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:34 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 23.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NeMo/Intf/data:setFirstParameter" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:36 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 24.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NeMo/Intf/data:setFirstParameter" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:37 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
curl -k -i --raw -o 25.dat -X POST "http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NMC:getWANStatus" -H "Host: 192.168.1.1" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Origin: http://192.168.1.1" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.73 Safari/537.36 OPR/34.0.2036.25" -H "X-Context: AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl" -H "Content-type: application/x-sah-ws-1-call+json; charset=UTF-8" -H "Accept: text/javascript" -H "X-Prototype-Version: 1.7" -H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" -H "Referer: http://192.168.1.1/advConfigAccessType.html" -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, lzma" -H "Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4" -H "Cookie: 46db1eb1/zoom-accessibility=small; 46db1eb1/contrast-accessibility=contrast1; 46db1eb1/language=pl; 46db1eb1/possibleLanguages=en,pl; 46db1eb1/sessid=MQcSNORlUtoe+b3DDwwgwuhk; 46db1eb1/context=AQ0BPWb8JMpzvU0gKzBTouV7eHtd6mNv3KWHvVD5xSuTBrXbPoT4HEZL0hM5tnnl; 46db1eb1/login=admin; 46db1eb1/accept-language=pl-PL,pl; 46db1eb1/expirydate=Wed Dec 23 2015 15:04:42 GMT+0100 (Środkowoeuropejski czas stand.)"
```

Comment: We need more informations to be able to help you, since we don't have/know your box.

Comment: What exact information? Not sure what more can I tell... Orange FunBox 2.0 is the same in all countries in Orange (I guess) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post is several years old, but I confirm having the same model (Funbox 2.0, Model:  Sagemcom CS 50001) and have figured it out in bash -

```
#!/bin/bash

cookie=`mktemp /dev/shm/curl.XXXXXXXXXX`

res=`curl "http://192.168.1.1/authenticate?username=$USER&password=$PASSWORD" --cookie-jar "$cookie" --data '' 2>/dev/null`
context=`python3 -c 'import json; d = json.loads("""'"$res"'"""); print(d["data"]["contextID"])'`

curl -s -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "X-Context: $context" --cookie "$cookie"     -d '{"parameters":{}}'  \
"http://192.168.1.1/sysbus/NMC:reboot"

rm "$cookie"
```

Essentially you have to set the session, get the Context ID and use it in the second command to actually reboot the router.

Answer (score 1):

Note that `/sysbus/NeMo/Intf/data:setFirstParameter` is invoked twice. In my case:

1. the first one is with `{name: "Enable", value: 0, flag: "ppp", traverse: "down"}`
2. the second one, right after the first one, with `{name: "Enable", value: 1, flag: "ppp", traverse: "down"}`

(Note the difference in `value`)

What happens if you try both requests?

Answer (score 1):

Another way, probably more convenient to a casual reader of this question, is to use the [`sysbus.py` script](https://github.com/rene-d/sysbus)  by René D. Février.

First, you need to configure it like described in the README (in french, but Google translate works well enough here), and then do something like:

```
./sysbus.py NeMo.Intf.data:setFirstParameter name=Enable value=0 flag=ppp traverse=down
./sysbus.py NeMo.Intf.data:setFirstParameter name=Enable value=1 flag=ppp traverse=down
```

Comment: Interesting, thanx for links